# If statement to check if variable landed on 2 numbers out of 10

Tags: c#, if-statement, random, int

I tried this code, but I'm getting an error. What is an alternative to this?

```
int chance = rand.Next(1, 11);

if (chance == 1 || 10)
{
    string win = "lose";
}
```

This is in C#

Comment: `if (chance == 1 || chance == 10)`

Comment: do you mean if (chance > 10) then lose?

Comment: I want to say else string win = "win"; but apparently I can't do that. What should I do instead?

Comment: @Asubaba see my answer below.

Comment: No Ajay, I want win to = "lose" if my rng lands on 1 or 10, otherwise I want it to = win

Comment: Just curious, any language support this convention `chance == 1 || 10` ?

Comment: @HariPrasad English does ;)

Comment: @Rob I got the answer... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Both operands of the OR (`||`) operator must be of type boolean. Thus you can't simply use `chance == 1 || 10` because the operand on the right side is of type `int`. So you have to take the long route :)

```
int chance = rand.Next(1, 11);
string win = "lose";

if (chance == 1 || chance == 10)
{
    win = "lose";
}
else
{
    win = "win";
}
```

I modified your code to declare the variable `win` outside the `if-else` block. Doing so will allow you to access it later if you need. (I am quite sure you are going to need it)

Comment: The declaration of `win` should be outside of the `if` block, otherwise you won't be able to access it outside of the `if` block scope.

Comment: @Steve correct, just copied OP's code :P

Comment: @Asubaba You may consider accepting this answer and upvoting it. It will help future readers.